# LOR from a Retired Professor

Tags: recommendation-letter

If my professor is retiring at the end of the semester, would his letter of recommendation carry weight when I apply for PhD programs eventually (later on)?

Comment: Of course it would, provided it is relevant timewise (i.e. not written years after he has become inactive).

Answer (score 4):

I don't see why it wouldn't. If your professor was fortunate enough to have a career at a university where he could properly retire from, then he must have had an outstanding reputation at his university and in his field.

Comment: I think the weight will have nothing to do with whether the professor is retired, and everything to do with the professor's own reputation (for instance the correlation between strong letters in the past and the success of students being recommended).